# help with grails map

Tags: java, grails, grails-controller

I'm trying to dynamically create a map collection but I am still new to grails and was hoping someone could help me.  What I want to do is parse and xml file and add the values to a map.  I've got the parsing down, but just dont know how to dynamically add the node values to the map.  here's what i have so far:

example xml stream:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
    <connections total="29">
      <person>
        <id>123245</id>
        <first-name>me</first-name>
        <last-name>you</last-name>          
      </person>
    </connections>
 </person>
```

I then parse it like this:

```
  def alum = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlResponse)
   alum.connections.person.each{ conName ->
print conName.'id'.toString() + " " +  conName.'first-name'.toString() + " " + conName.'last-name'.toString() + "\n"
   }
```

So, this allows me to iterate over, and parse, the xml stream.  my question is, if i wanted to add the values, dynamically, to a map like this:

```
   def myMap= [fName:"SomeName", lName:"Sme last Name", id:1234]
```

how would i do this?

Thank you 
jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the child node names and want to use them as the keys in the map, use this:

```
def alum = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlResponse)
alum.connections.person.each { conName ->
   def myMap = [:]
   conName.children().each { child -> myMap[child.name()] = child.text() }
}
```

This will result in `[id: '123245', 'first-name': 'me', 'last-name': 'you']`

Unrelated: you can shorted up your debug code with a GString:

```
print "${conName.'id'} ${conName.'first-name'} ${conName.'last-name'}\n"
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  I should have stated that, in my xml example, there are multiple rows of data.  the example you provided seems to work but it only seems to get the last row.  how do i store all records in the map?  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an updated example that demonstrates multiple rows of data?

Answer (score 0):

well, i ended up just using a multidimensional array, and that seems to have worked fine.  Thanks again for your help

```
int i=0
String[][] friends = new String[test][4]
alum.connections.person.each{ conName ->
friends[i][0] =conName.'id'.toString()
friends[i][1] =conName.'first-name'.toString()
friends[i][2] =conName.'last-name'.toString()
friends[i][3] =conName.'picture-url'.toString()
i++
}
[Friends:friends]
```

This way, i was able to pass it on to my groovy page and iterate over the array

Comment: do it the groovy way: `def friends = [:]; friends[i] = [:]; friends[i][0] = conName.'id'.toString()`